# Export to individual pdf when filter is selected automate in Power BI service or desktop

Tags: powerbi, export-to-pdf

Is there a way to export the PDFs from Power Bi service automatically or in less time?  I need to get PDF report for each student  in every class with the filter of each student is selected and they're hundreds .

Please let me know if something doesn't make sense in the question?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Power BI premium? If yes, you can automate this using Microsft Flow/Power Automate.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide the steps please in Power Automate?

Comment: Please refer to this article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export

Comment: Did it help to achieve the goal?

Comment: I dont have premium license so I could not work on it. Thank you for all the suggestions.